# How much in-universe time has passed during the three seasons of the Orville?

Tags: the-orville

How much time has passed between season 1 episode 1 and season 3 episode 11 of the Orville?

I'm looking for an answer based on in-universe time using canonical sources, rather than user opinion. This isn't an opinion based question, but one that needs facts, sources and references.

For example, using the show's equivalent of Stardates.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe *The Orville* uses Stardates but rather retains the current CE year numbering.

### 3 Years

This is from a [**Fan Wiki**](https://orville.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline#:%7E:text=The%20series%20premiere%20opens%20with,April%20or%20May%20of%202420.) so it may not be authoritative...

> The series premiere opens with Kelly Grayson's affair in the fall of 2418 before jumping to September 2419 when Ed Mercer becomes captain of the USS Orville. The show briefly enters the 29th century in Pria. Season 1 concludes in April or May of 2420.
>
> Season 1.5 takes place over the summer of 2420 with glimpses of the early 24th century in New Beginnings, Pt. 1 and glimpses of the early winter of 2420 in The Word of Avis, Pt. 1.
>
> Season 2 commences around August 2420. The cold opening of All the World is Birthday Cake takes place around the year 2417 on Regor 2. The season concludes in May 2421.
>
> Season 2.5 takes place exactly 12 months after the conclusion of Season 1.5. Launch Day, Pt. 1 opens in 2400 aboard the USS Bohr before jumping to July 2421.
>
> Season 3 commences in early 2422; events in the latter half of season 2 are said to >have taken place "last year".

Comment: Where are those dates given, are they on screen?

Comment: I don't believe they are shown on screen, perhaps from dialogue?

Comment: Of course you are making a big assumption that the dates give are CE.  There are many different calendar eras already used on one planet, Earth.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_era

Comment: CE is confirmed in the latest episode.